# How to fix 404 error on deployed Angular app that is served by NGINX

Tags: angular, nginx

I have an application that I have already deployed on a server the issue that every time I reload a certain page I get a NGINX's 404 error. I'm using Docker to run the application. below is my NGINX config file.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;

    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        #
        # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        #
        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
    }
    if ($request_method = 'POST') {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
    }
    if ($request_method = 'GET') {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
    }
  }
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# stage 1 
FROM node:latest as node 

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .


RUN npm i -f

# RUN npm audit fix

# RUN npm install 

RUN npm run build --aot

# stage 2 
FROM nginx:alpine 
COPY --from=node /app/dist/e-county /usr/share/nginx/html
```

The commands I'm using to run the docker file:

```
docker build --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t e-county:v1 .

docker run --rm -d -p 80:80 e-county:v1
```

Comment: Is nginx to route to your app outside of a Docker container? And how are you serving your app? (what is inside your Dockerfile)

Comment: @Carsten I have added the docker file for more details.

Comment: You are using the default nginx config inside the Dockerfile to serve the app? The default config has `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;`. My `try_files` is `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` to make sure it falls back to the index.html. I made a `default.conf` file and copied that to the default configuration location using this in the Dockerfile: `COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/`. Want me to post an answer including the file contents?

Comment: @Carsten sure you can share the I'd like to check the Dockerfile and default,conf file

Comment: What I didn't do was to overwrite Nginx default config with the docker file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My `default.conf` file contains a `try_files` with `/index.html` as a fallback:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <obfuscated>;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

My Dockefile looks like this:

```
FROM nginx:alpine

RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: I used your default.conf  file configs and it has worked.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually ended up coming up with the below docker.

**Dockerfile**

```
# stage 1 
FROM node:latest as node 

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .


RUN npm i -f

RUN npm audit fix

# RUN npm install 

RUN npm run build --aot

# stage 2 
FROM nginx:alpine 


RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

COPY  --from=node /app/nginx/*  /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=node /app/dist/e-county /usr/share/nginx/html
```